# Homebrew: list the packages installed from taps?

Tags: homebrew

Over time, I've installed a number of packages with Homebrew, mostly from the default repo of formulae ([homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core)), but some from other locations via `brew tap`.

Now I'm putting together some install scripts to make my dev environment more reproducible, and I'm trying to figure out which packages can be installed by a simple `brew install` and which require a `brew tap` beforehand.

The ability to [query brew](http://docs.brew.sh/Querying-Brew.html) has proved useful for figuring out which options I used for each package, but not for this tap-related question. Is there a way to do this without manually going through each package and seeing where it's available?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I found a couple ways that work.

```
brew list --full-name
```

Slower, but a little more informative:

```
brew info $(brew list) | grep '^From:' | sort
```

Comment: There's also `brew tap-info --installed`

Comment: This also works for brew cask: `brew cask info $(brew cask list) | grep '^From:' | sort`

Answer (score 9):

This expression would return a list of *installed 3rd party packages* only:

```
brew list --full-name -1 | grep /
```

…for the respective list of *taps* in use, try:

```
brew list --full-name -1 | grep / | cut -d"/" -f1 -f2 | sort | uniq
```

Comment: With `cut (GNU coreutils) 8.32`, the second command needs to be modified to `brew list --full-name -1 | grep / | cut -d"/" -f1,2 | sort | uniq`

Comment: I think Homebrew only shows third-party packages with full name. For example, tap `homebrew-cask-versions` isn’t considered third-party. Is there any way to list casks not from `homebrew-cask`?

Answer (score 0):

The `brew list --full-name` variants in the other answers did not work for me (in 2022). This, however, does:

`brew list -1 | xargs brew info | grep '^From:'`

Alternatively, to see only casks, use this:

`brew list --cask -1 | xargs brew info --cask | grep '^From:'`

... or only leaves:

`brew leaves | xargs brew info | grep '^From:'`